# How to use setInterval() as an event listener

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've never used `setInterval()` and I need some advice as I can't get my head round this. I want to create some kind of event listener.

Say for example I want to check the length of options in a Select Menu however a third party script populates the content of the Select Menu via an Ajax request. Unfortunately I'm not allowed to touch the the third party script so I though about having a function that waits and listens for the content to be added and can then perform it's tasks.

say I have the following on my web page:

```
<select size="7" id="cat"> </select>
```

onload this gets filled with options like this:

```
<option value="Category 1">Category 1</option>
<option value="Category 2">Category 2</option>
<option value="Category 3">Category 3</option>
<option value="Category 4">Category 4</option>
```

I was going to add a function that also loads onLoad (or $(document).ready() to be exact) that will listen to the length of the options and if greater than zero we wish to do something (in this example an alert)

```
function checkLen(){

    if($('#cat option').size() > 0){
        return true;
       }else{
        return false;
       }

}


function takeDefault(){

    var ourInterval = setInterval("checkLen();", 1000);

       if(ourInterval == true){
           alert("Okay I will do something now");
           clearInterval(ourInterval);

       }

        // Now I will perform some other tasks
}

$(document).ready(function() {
   takeDefault();
});
```

Now this just doesn't work as I don't really understand. The if(checkLen == True) condition is only done once and I need this to be done every second until the select menu is populated.

Comment: you dont need to use a string for setInterval, just have `setInterval(checklen, 1000);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For simplicity I used different elements, but the idea is still the same:

```
var listen = setInterval(function () {
    if ($('input').val().length > 0) {
        console.log('has changed, should call callback');
        clearInterval(listen);
    }
}, 1000);​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/suKCp/

For your case this should be something like (untested):

```
function takeDefault(){
  var ourInterval = setInterval(function () {
    if ($('#cat option').size() > 0) {
      alert("Okay I will do something now");
      clearInterval(ourInterval);
    }
  }, 1000);

  // Now I will perform some other tasks
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ourInterval` is NOT the return value of function executed by `setInterval`.  It is the value you can use to cancel the interval.

Second, instead of checking at an interval, why not just register a listener on the input, and do something when it changes?

Something like

http://jsfiddle.net/BskPK/

Comment: Sorry that was a typo in my code, I've amended it now... sorry

Comment: note that the change event is when the *value* of the element changes, not when the innerHTML/content changes.